# How can I make a Xml output to file?

Tags: xml, laravel, filesystems, storage

I have a xml output. I convert an array to xml. But how can I convert this output as a file? I need to store this file my storage folder because I want to download it when it is necessary. So imagine something like that:

1. Given we have a table
2. Then we convert table datas to xml.
3. Then it should store as an xml file
4. When we hit a button
5. It should download as a xml file.

I need last 3 steps to get it work. Many thanks..

Comment: Could you post some code to illustrute your attempt to solve as well as description of the problem you faced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be enough for your task.

From laravel docs:

1. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#storing-files
2. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#retrieving-files

Comment: Ahh thank you. Storage::put('file.jpg', $contents); This will enough to convert a content to file,  right? May I ask , The put methots first argument should be name of file or place and name ? I mean how laravel knows what type of file should be?

Comment: you can specify .xml, as you see in the example there is .jpg. First param is path, single file name is also a path. Try to create put('name_of_file.xml', $xml_code) and check storage folder, try to find where laravel has created your file. After you could add specific path (e.g. path/to/your/folder/name_of_file.xml, $xml_code)

Answer (score 0):

After @Aleksandrs answer I figured out. And problem solved.

I did something like that.

```
 public function downloadXml($filename = '')
{
    $fields = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    $products = Product::where('user_id', auth()->id())->exclude($fields)->get()->toArray();
    $products = array_collapse($products);

    // dd($products);
    $result = ArrayToXml::convert($products, 'product');

    Storage::put(auth()->id().'File/products.xml', $result);
}
```